# android facebook webview login does not bring user login

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, webview

guys
I am trying to login facebook from embedded webview in android app. 
I am able to login from android chrome browser from my website login page successfully. however, when I try to do the same in webview,it brings me back to my website login page without taking me login through.

I checked facebook developer site, it says:
"Native iOS and Android apps must not use their own web views for Facebook Login."
Link : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/06/26/october-2013-platform-changes/

Can I login FB from android webview? or I need to implement fb login with fb SDK and use API provided by serverside to complete this process?

Thanks in advance!
Leon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@takrishna. I managed to make FB login provided by website work in webview. The key point is that FB login javascript opens a new window when initializing a session for authentication with FB server. I create a new webview for FB login page. We need to keep website login page open which initialises the FB authentication, and once Fb authenticates user successfully, we close the new webview . After that website login webview receives callback and proceed user to login.

I agree that it is better to handle the FB login flow native for better user experience.

Comment: how you managed to make those changes? Would you mind sharing few code example or documents?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I login FB from android webview?

No you cannot - you have answer in your link !

*To provide a better experience for all Facebook Login users, we are changing our policy to prohibit native iOS and Android apps from using custom web views for Facebook login.*

> I need to implement fb login with fb SDK and use API provided by serverside to complete this process?

Yes - you rock !

Comment: Hi, takrishna and Pang. thanks for your answer. are the same for google plus and linkedIn shared login from webview? thanks!

Comment: @LeonLi they eventually will get there - I recommend you to explore cordova/phonegap plugin for facebook sdk or  any social integration..

Comment: something like - https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4 - may be check for something that is more active !! - in case you don't know Cordova - it is a library that brings native SDKs/implementation to be accessible from webview/hybrid

Comment: Guys, what about native android development. Can I somehow login with google plus/facebook through standart Android WebView, or maby there are some "platform independent browser" for android to include in my APK? Thanks.

Comment: For native apps look for FB/Google SDK for android native development - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/